# Jsoup - seprate all url while download text of a page

Tags: java, jsoup

How can i use in jsoup to remove all the link while downloading a webpage.

I use the following code which give me text of a webpage

```
public static void Url(String urlTosearch) throws IOException {
        URL = urlTosearch;
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
         String textOnly = Jsoup.parse(doc.toString()).text();
        Output ob = new Output();
        ob.Write(textOnly);

    }
```

but is there any way through which i can separate all link while downloading text of a page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i use in jsoup to remove all the link while downloading a webpage

You can select all `a` elements with `href` attribute and `remove` it from `Document` object representing DOM structure of your page.

So your code can look like

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();
doc.select("a[href]").remove();//remove all found `<a href...>` elements from DOM
String textOnly = doc.text();//generate text from DOM without your links
```

Comment: It is showing me error : java.net.SocketTimeoutException

Comment: @AyushRajniwal It is because default timeout is 3000 milliseconds (3 seconds) and your page wans't able to be downloded on that time (maybe server was overloaded). In that case consider setting this value higher like 10 seconds `Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).timeout(10000).get();`. You can always set timeout to `0` which means that this will wait infinitely, but IMO it is better to have some max value after which we will stop waiting for data from server.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like that :

```
public static void Url (String urlTosearch) throws IOException {
    URL = urlTosearch;
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(URL).get();

    // Take all links in the page
    Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");
    for (Element link : links) { // Iter on each links to get URL
        String relHref = link.attr("href"); // Get relative URL
        String absHref = link.attr("abs:href"); // Get absolute URL
        // I let you do whatever you want with urls
    }

}
```